# DynamoDBIndexHashKey annotation on entity field make queries fail

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, spring-data

Using the DynamoDb with Spring Data. I specify the following entity:

```
    // getters and setters added by Lombok
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "secret-table")
    public class SecretEntity {

        @Id
        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "uuid")
        @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
        private String id;

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "status")
        private String status;

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "reference")
        private String secretReference;

        @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "secretContractUuid", globalSecondaryIndexName = "secretContractUuid")
        private String contractUuid;
    }
```

And trying to access entries using `contract` field and getting error:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::12313123123:user/dynamo-user is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-east-2:131234234:table/secret-table/index/secretContractUuid because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:Query action (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: PJ1LOFVG3LSGLTSCIKM9JAOBG3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
```

But if I am specifying this field using just

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "secretContractUuid")
```

It is working fine.

When the @DynamoDBIndexHashKey is required for the GSI field? Are there some performance issues in cases when this annotation is not specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by lack of permissions on the index. By annotating `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey` you are telling the application that it can use the index, but you are not supplying adequate permissions.

Your policy should look something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AccessTableAndIndex",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "dynamodb:*",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/secret-table",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/Books/index/secretContractUuid"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any info on what happens if not specifying @DynamoDBIndexHashKey? Why it is even working in that case?

Comment: I believe adding "index/*" would allow all the indexes access then?

Comment: If you don't specify then you never access the index, so you don't get permission denied. And yes `index/*`  would provide access to all indexes.